# CSS file unable to load relative URL of image

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to set a background image in my CSS file:

Page HTML:

```
<span class="mobile-menu-logo"></span>
```

CSS:

```
.mobile-menu-logo { 
    display: block;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('http://192.168.254.5/phd/assets/css/img/mobile-menu-icon.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: 130px 30px;
}
```

File structure:

```
/phd/assets/css/style.css
/phd assets/css/img/mobile-menu-icon.png
```

When I specify the entire URL, the image shows. However, when I update the CSS to:

```
background: url('/img/mobile-menu-icon.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;
```

or:

```
background: url('img/mobile-menu-icon.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;
```

... the image is not found.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I

Comment: Whether It is from server folder or local folder?

Comment: @praveen I am running this site on my local machine for right now. The IP address is shown in my above question. I don't want to put the entire URL in the CSS file, because if the user is viewing over a secure connection, it will break the HTTPS.

Comment: I am guessing that you need to add the `/phd assets/css` before the `/img/mobile-menu-icon.png` and it will work. I think the base folder that it is looking for is further down from where the image is stored.

Comment: @JROB From what I can tell, the method without a leading slash should be working, but you can surely also get it to work by starting the path with `/phd/...`.

Comment: @JROB Did you check the error with debugger in browser?